# Internet Explorer Smooth Scrolling Detection

Tags: internet-explorer, smooth-scrolling

This is a two part question.  I building a web page and I need to know:

1. Is there a way to detect if IE has smooth scrolling enabled (if so, how)?
2. Is there a way to force IE to turn off smooth scrolling for my web page?

To be clear, I'm not asking how to turn off smooth scrolling for the whole computer.  I am the developer developing a web page that will only work properly if smooth scrolling is disabled.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. No
2. No

In conclusion, IE sucks. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm just chirping in here 5 years later...

You can remove smooth scrolling in IE if you manually override the event yourself.

```
if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident\/7\./)) {
    $('body').on("mousewheel", function () {
        event.preventDefault();
        var wd = event.wheelDelta;
        var csp = window.pageYOffset;
        window.scrollTo(0, csp - wd);
    });
}
```

This was sufficient for me to resolve my IE smooth scrolling issues.
Blatantly stolen from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29416448/how-to-disable-smooth-scrolling-in-ie11)